# How to get the name of class that used the method

Tags: class, c#-4.0, get, names

In this method I write an error message. I need to write the name of current class that used this method instead of {0}.
Hope my problem is clear. Thanks.

```
class WriteEx
{
    public void WriteFormatExceptionError(string value, Exception ex, Logger logger)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Error occured in {0}. Cannot convert input string to double. Input string value: {1}.", **class name that used this method**, value);
        logger.WriteLog(message, ex);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` is quite slow!

```
var st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();

if (st.FrameCount > 1) {
    // GetFrame(0) returns the current method.
    var frame = st.GetFrame(1);
    var method = frame.GetMethod();
    var methodName = method.Name;

    // method.DeclaringType is a Type. You could even use
    // method.DeclaringType.FullName
    var methodClass = method.DeclaringType.Name;
}
```